# Right triangle inscribed in circle: find side length as function of arc length

Tags: geometry

**The problem was worded incorrectly, $s$ was supposed to be the length of the chord $CA$, not the arc!!! It makes sense now.**

Given the right triangle $\triangle ABC$ inscribed inside a circle of radius $R$, I need to find the length of side c as a function of the arc $s$ between $C$ and $A$.

Here is what I have:
$$ c^2 = R^2 - b^2 = 4R^2 - 4R^2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} = 4R^2 \left(1 - \sin^2 \frac{s}{2R} \right) = 4R^2 \cos^2 \frac{s}{R} $$

I'm supposed to get that:
$$ c^2 \stackrel{?}= 4R^2 -s^2 $$

Does it mean that
$$ s = 4R^2 \sin^2 \frac{s}{2R}? $$

If so, how?

I'd really appreciate if you could help me out.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: In fact $c^2=(2R)^2-b^2$

Comment: This leaves $c^2=4R^2\left(1-\sin^2\frac{s}{2R}\right)$ and you can use $\cos 2\alpha=1-\sin^2\alpha$ to write $c^2=4R^2\cos\frac{s}{R}$, but I don't know how to proceed from here

Comment: Of course, thanks for pointing it out! I will now edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$\alpha=\frac sR$$
$$\beta = \pi-\alpha=\pi-\frac sR$$

[image]

Draw $OD$ perpendicular to $AB$

$$c=AB=AD+DB=2AD$$
$$AD=R\sin\frac\beta2$$
$$c=2R\sin(\frac\pi2-\frac s{2R})=2R\cos\frac s{2R}$$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! Do you know how do I go from there? I need to get $ c = \sqrt{ 4R^2 - s}$

Comment: The dimensions of what you want is incorrect. Please check it again

Comment: sorry, I meant: $c = \sqrt{R^2 - s^2}$

Comment: The problem I was working on wasn't worded correctly, I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks for helping me out! And may I ask, where do you make those cool graphics?

Comment: Geogebra... you may check other answers of mine. I try to provide visual/intuitive answers using these graphics... Thanks for the appreciation :)